# How do I make some attributes accessible only to Users that have a specific role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `User` model, I have this:

```
attr_accessible :role_ids, :as => :admin
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

I want this particular attribute to be only accessible if the `current_user.can?(:edit, Role)` - i.e. only users with a role of `admin` or `superadmin` should be able to access those attributes.

How do I do this?

Edit 1: I am using Devise, CanCan & Rolify.

Comment: What's with the downvote and the close vote? Care to offer an explanation?

Comment: What have you got installed? Are you using Cancan and devise? The downvote is probably lack of info.

Comment: @simonmorley Yes, CanCan & Devise. Sorry, will update question.

Comment: Hey. Presumably you've already sorted your abilities and have cancan working in general? In rails3, you can't limit attr accessible to a role. A big problem in my mind. However there's a gem called strong parameters that getting introduced in R4. I'll add an answer in a min as I think this'll help you.

Comment: @simonmorley Yes, I have those done. Your answer is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like I said, we think the best way to restrict attributes to certain roles is to use the [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem that DHH introduced recently. This will also be part of Rails4 thankfully.

Even if it doesn't fit, it's a good idea to start integrating the principles as it will make your Rails 3 to 4 upgrade easier.

If you have a Railscasts Pro membership, Ryan Bates has made another [fantastic tutorial](http://railscasts.com/episodes/371-strong-parameters?view=asciicast) on it.

In brief, here's what's recommended in that Railscast.

After installing the gem, remove attr_accessible from your model.

**Add this to an initializer:**

```
ActiveRecord::Base.send(:include,  ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesProtection)
```

**Alter your update action in your controller::**

```
def update
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  if @topic.update_attributes(topic_params)
    redirect_to topics_url, notice: "Updated topic."
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

**Create a private method in your controller:**

```
 def topic_params
   if current_user && current_user.admin?
     params[:topic].permit(:name, :sticky)
    else
      params[:topic].permit(:name)
    end
  end
```

In your situation, like we do, you'd have to change the topic_params method to use your roles.

There's a few more suggestions in the RailsCast and it's really worth the $9! (I'm in no way affiliated with the site, it's just proven invaluable to us)

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This looks like what I need. I actually had been holding out on getting the pro version of RailsCast - but I did recently buy a subscription and it has proven very helpful. Just doing a quick overview of both the `strong_parameters` gem, and this RailsCast it looks like it is what I need.

Comment: It's initially more work than you'd have probably hoped but well worth it in the long run. Good luck. S

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking....oy veeyy....this looks like a headache. But, I don't have a choice - and the availability of a RailsCast makes it much easier to manage.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have any experience with shopping carts? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899686/using-acts-as-shopping-cart-how-do-i-implement-basic-quantity-editing  I am trying to implement a regular shopping cart solution but don't want to use spree. Unfortunately, Ryan hasn't done a recent cast on that topic :(

Comment: can you please clarify what you mean by this 'include in your initializer?' what file is that?

Comment: @oFca You can create an initialiser with any name. foo_bar.rb and place in initializers. Then restart your application.

Comment: @marcamillion Made a small comment on that post. S

Answer (score 0):

in my user model

```
class User
  attr_accessible :nickname, as: :admin
end
```

in my rails console

```
User.first.update_attributes!({nickname: "uschi"})
# WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: nickname

User.first.update_attributes!({nickname: "uschi"}, {as: :admin})
# true
```

UPDATE

maybe i am to stupid to get your problem, but just do a

```
if current_user.can?(:edit, Role)
  user.update_attributes!({nickname: "uschi"}, {as: :admin})
else
  first.update_attributes!({nickname: "uschi"})
end
```

and there are probably smarter ways of doing this...

Comment: I need this to work with roles specified in my `Ability` model - for CanCan & Rolify. With `:as => :admin` it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah that's not right with Cancan as it looks like you're creating a Boolean value for admin.

Comment: Yeh... @simonmorley is spot-on. I am trying to restrict access to some attributes on the model, using CanCan & Rolify. What you suggested is something you would do on a controller or in a view or something. I need to do it in my model.