# Deconstructing Rails .joins & .where methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have two models - `Banner` and `BannerType`.

Their schema looks like this:

**Banner**

```
# Table name: banners
#
#  id             :integer          not null, primary key
#  name           :string(255)
#  image          :string(255)
#  created_at     :datetime         not null
#  updated_at     :datetime         not null
#  url            :string(255)
#  banner_type_id :integer
```

**BannerType**

```
# Table name: banner_types
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
```

`Banner belongs_to :banner_type` and `BannerType has_many :banners`

I have two records in BannerType that are these:

```
BannerType.all
  BannerType Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "banner_types".* FROM "banner_types" 
 => [#<BannerType id: 1, name: "Featured", created_at: "2012-12-17 04:35:24", updated_at: "2012-12-17 04:35:24">, #<BannerType id: 2, name: "Side", created_at: "2012-12-17 04:35:40", updated_at: "2012-12-17 04:35:40">]
```

If I want to do a query to find all the banners of the type `Featured` I can do something like this:

```
Banner.joins(:banner_type).where("banner_types.name = ?", 'Featured')
```

I know that I could also query by the `banner_type_id => 1` but that is germane to this particular question.

If we break down that statement, there are a few things that are a bit confusing to me.

1. `Banner.join(:banner_type)` - would generate `NoMethodError: undefined method 'join' for #<Class:0x007fb6882909f0>` Why is there no Rails method called `join` when that is the SQL method name?
2. Why do I do `Banner.joins(:banner_type)` i.e. the singular `banner_type` when the table name is `banner_types`. Am I not joining the Banner & BannerType tables (which Rails conventions denote as plural). If I try `Banner.joins(:banner_types)` this is the error that I get:

   `Banner.joins(:banner_types)
   ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'banner_types' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?`
3. Why does the `where` clause need `banner_types` and not `banner_type` (i.e. the pluralized version - i.e. the table name and not the symbol used in the `joins` method? It seems it would be more intuitive if you use the table names in both places or use the symbol names in both places. If at the very least, for consistency purposes.
4. Why can't I do dynamic finding via associations - i.e. it would be nice if I could do `Banner.find_by_banner_type_name("Featured")`?

Would love to hear your thoughts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### #1

> Banner.join(:banner_type) - would generate NoMethodError: undefined method 'join' for # Why is there no Rails method called join when that is the SQL method name?

It's clearer when read as plain English to say "Banner joins banner type" vs. "Banner join banner type". I'm not sure there's more of a reason than that.

---

#### #2

> Why do I do Banner.joins(:banner_type) i.e. the singular banner_type when the table name is banner_types. Am I not joining the Banner & BannerType tables (which Rails conventions denote as plural). If I try Banner.joins(:banner_types) this is the error that I get:
>
> Banner.joins(:banner_types) ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'banner_types' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?

In `.joins(:banner_type)`, `:banner_type` is the relation you're joining on, not the table. You have

```
has_one :banner_type
```

so that is what Rails joins on. This is just how Rails works when you pass a Symbol to `.joins`, and is why the error refers to the association when you pass a Symbol not matching any existing assocation for your model.

This is also why you're able to do `JOIN`'s multiple levels deep using symbols for the nested associations, as described [in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-nested-associations-multiple-level)

```
Category.joins(:posts => [{:comments => :guest}, :tags])
```

Also described [in the Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#using-a-string-sql-fragment), you can pass Strings to `.joins` as well.

```
Client.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN addresses ON addresses.client_id = clients.id')
```

Note in this last example, when a String is passed to `joins`, the **table name** `addresses` is used, *not* an association name; this helps answer **#3**.

---

#### #3

> Why does the where clause need banner_types and not banner_type (i.e. the pluralized version - i.e. the table name and not the symbol used in the joins method? It seems it would be more intuitive if you use the table names in both places or use the symbol names in both places. If at the very least, for consistency purposes.

After a bit of string interpolation, Strings passed to the `where` method *(similar to `joins`)* are more or less passed directly into the final SQL query *(there will be a bit of manipulation by ARel along the way)*. `name` is an ambiguous column *(both your `banners` and `banner_types` tables have a `name` column)*, so referring to the table by it's full path `[TABLE NAME].[COLUMN NAME]` is required. If, for example you had some `color` column in `banner_types` *(that didn't also exist in `banners`)*, there's no need to use it as `"banner_types.color = ?"` in your `where` method; `"color = ?"` will work just fine.

Note, just like in **#2**, you can pass symbols to the `where` method for `JOIN`'d tables.

```
Banner.joins(:banner_type).where(banner_type: [name: 'Featured'])
```

---

#### #4

> Why can't I do dynamic finding via associations - i.e. it would be nice if I could do Banner.find_by_banner_type_name("Featured")?

You can't do a find like that because it's not supported in ARel, it's that simple really *(IMO, a method name like `find_by_banner_type_name` quite confusing)*.

Comment: Wow...thanks for this comprehensive solution - but just to point out one solution to #4 that someone else answered by has since deleted is: `BannerType.find_by_name('Featured').banners`. That would kinda satisfy my last question, although a bit backwards. I do get your point though...that can get a bit confusing.

Comment: Also...re: #2, I don't have `has_one :banner_type` explicitly. Are you saying that because `Banner belongs_to :banner_type`? So that in effect is a `has_one` relationship?

Comment: Does the query (the join) even work without the `has_one` association defined? I've never tried that. I'm also curious if there's a reason why you *don't* have that explicitly defined.

Comment: It works perfectly right now, and I don't have `has_one` defined. I just have `has_many :banners` on the `BannerType` model, and `belongs_to :banner_type` on the `Banner` model. Works like a charm.

Comment: A bit off-topic, but do you have any experience with `acts_as_shopping_cart`? I need some help with this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899686/using-acts-as-shopping-cart-how-do-i-implement-basic-quantity-editing

Comment: No, I've never used it, but will take a look at the question.

Comment: late to the party, but as to #1 : `join` is a method on `Array` ; as `ActiveRecord::Relation` delegates any method it does not know to an underlying lazy-loaded `Array` of records, if you call `join` you will hit the array method. I guess the reason for `joins` with an extra `s` is to 1) avoid confusion between the methods 2) avoid masking the `join` method (don't ask me why, i don't see in which case it would be useful) 3) make `Relation`'s interface feel like an array on steroids