# Routing Error for a model with a join_table and has_many :through in RailsAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

So I have 3 models: `category`, `product`, `category_products`.

This is my `category.rb`

```
  attr_accessible :name
    has_many :category_products do
         def with_products
           includes(:product)
         end
       end

  has_many :products, :through => :category_products
```

This is my `product.rb`

```
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :vendor_id, :image, :category_ids

    belongs_to :vendor
    has_many :category_products do
           def with_categories
             includes(:category)
           end
    end

    has_many :categories, :through => :category_products
```

This is my `category_product.rb`

```
  attr_accessible :product_id, :category_id, :purchases_count

    belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category

  validates_uniqueness_of :product_id, :scope => :category_id
```

This is my `routes.rb`

```
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'
  resources :categories
  resources :vendors do
      resources :products
  end

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => 'home#index'
  end

  root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users
  resources :users
```

When I click on `Categories` when I am viewing RailsAdmin, I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /admin/category

Message No route matches {:action=>"show", :model_name=>"category_product", :id=>nil, :controller=>"rails_admin/main"}
```

I also get this error when I click on `Category Products`

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /admin/category_product

Message SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: category_products.desc: SELECT "category_products".* FROM "category_products" ORDER BY category_products. desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

All other links within RailsAdmin for my other 'normal' (i.e. non HMT) models work.

What could be causing this?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**

For what it's worth, here are the logs when I click on 'Categories' inside of Rails Admin:

```
CodeRay::Scanners could not load plugin nil; falling back to :text
CodeRay::Scanners could not load plugin nil; falling back to :text


Started GET "/admin/category?_pjax=%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-20 22:23:38 -0500
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"_pjax"=>"[data-pjax-container]", "model_name"=>"category"}
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 6
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" ORDER BY categories.id desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
  CategoryProduct Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "category_products".* FROM "category_products" WHERE "category_products"."category_id" = 2
  Rendered /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@apt-605/gems/rails_admin-0.3.0/app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml within layouts/rails_admin/pjax (29.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 43ms
CodeRay::Scanners could not load plugin nil; falling back to :text
CodeRay::Scanners could not load plugin nil; falling back to :text


Started GET "/admin/category" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-20 22:23:40 -0500
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"model_name"=>"category"}
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" LIMIT 6
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" ORDER BY categories.id desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
  CategoryProduct Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "category_products".* FROM "category_products" WHERE "category_products"."category_id" = 2
  Rendered /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@apt-605/gems/rails_admin-0.3.0/app/views/rails_admin/main/index.html.haml within layouts/rails_admin/application (30.5ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 251ms
```

**Edit 2**

Here is a [gist of the full trace](https://gist.github.com/e0f9e0d399791be038ef) of the error. I am using the gem better_errors, so the trace doesn't look like a standard Rails trace error. But the data is the same.

**Edit 3**

This is the schema for my 3 models:

`CategoryProducts`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: category_products
#
#  product_id      :integer
#  category_id     :integer
#  purchases_count :integer          default(0)
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
```

`Category`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
```

`Product`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  price       :float
#  vendor_id   :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  image       :string(255)
```

Notice that `CategoryProduct` doesn't have a primary key field. Is that the issue?

Comment: nothing to do with moving your do in resources ,so resources :categories do resources :vendors resources :products ?

Comment: Hrmm...not sure I follow what you mean. You mean nesting `products` within `vendors` within `categories`?

Comment: yeah, its something i have done in the past with no problems, not saying its a fix but worth a shot for the sake of moving do :)

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here. That would also change the structure of the routes of my app - which I don't want to do. Why would I want to move the `do`?

Comment: have you at least tried?

Comment: Yep...and it didn't fix this error...unfortunately :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check all the CategoryProduct objects have foreign keys: category_id and product_id.

```
CategoryProduct.all.each {|c| raise("Repair #{c.id}") unless c.category && c.product}
```

**Dec 21 update:**

How i've installed brand new Rails 3.2.9 with Category, Product and CategoryProduct. Model's relationship code is identical, RailsAdmin with default settings.

And it works with no any problems!

I decided to test my hypothesis. I think maybe when you went from the HABTM to the HM2HM you have missed (forgot) to reestablish key column ID for CategoryProduct which is now not just a join-model, but an independent entity.

So, routing error like:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :model_name=>"category_product", :id=>nil, :controller=>"rails_admin/main"}
```

can be result of *missing id*.

Well I disabled CategoryProduct's id field manually (def id; nil; end).

and yes it is:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :model_name=>"category_product", :id=>nil, :controller=>"rails_admin/main"}
```

Comment: Controller for `category_products`?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work :( I also created the `category_products` controller with a `show` action, and it is still giving me that error.

Comment: I have added log output that happens whenever this error is generated (at the very least, the first error in my question).

Comment: Ok, look at DB table 'category_products' (directly through any db client): all items must have product_id and category_id. During active development we can let it happen very often. "no such column: category_products.desc:" - funny stuff. ))

Comment: im looking rails_admin sources. Nothing to do with routes. problem in something another

Comment: Do that at my console? Or in a controller action?

Comment: Btw...isn't this just a temporary fix? I want to prevent this error when I push it to Heroku.

Comment: Also, I just tried this in my console and it hasn't helped :( Still getting this error. FYI: I reverted the `routes.rb` to its original state.

Comment: I checked the db table `category_products` in SQLite Browser. All items have both a `product_id` and `category_id`.

Comment: I have updated the question with a link to the gist with the trace.

Comment: what happen when you override your CategoryProduct with: def id; 4; end ? it look like your model has no id or something.

Comment: I repeated your application: Rails 3.2.9, Category/Product/CategoryProduct + RailsAdmin. Look up results:)

Comment: I updated the question with the schemas for my 3 models. Can you tell me if there is anything missing there.

Comment: yes it is. remove ":id => false" from category_products migration, drop table and create it again

Comment: Given that you have been my fairy godmother for these issues, care to take a look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899686/using-acts-as-shopping-cart-how-do-i-implement-basic-quantity-editing ? :D

Comment: Argh...now getting the `column doesn't exist error` from Heroku - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998507/heroku-actionviewtemplateerror-pgerror-error-column-category-products

Comment: Totally nailed it @ValeryKvon. I had a model with _id: nil, and that prevented the page from loading.  Thank you!