# How do I implement nested instances of the same model? E.g. a category within a category?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `category` model, which is basically what `products` will be assigned to.

So my `category` model looks like this:

```
attr_accessible :name
has_many :category_products do
  def with_products
    includes(:product)
  end
end

has_many :products, :through => :category_products
```

What I would like to do is to have categories within categories - so a product should be able to be put in `Men` and then `Shoes`.

That way, I can have a `Men` drop-down menu, that produces all the subcategories within `Men` like `Shoes`.

But, if a user clicks on `Men` they will see all the products in that category.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a gem like [Ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to organize your categories into a hierarchy.

If you only need one level deep of nesting, you can use a self-join.

```
belongs_to :parent_category, class: "Category"
has_many :subcategories, class: "Category"
```

You'll also need a migration to add `category_id` to your `category` table.

Stick a drop down in your `app/views/categories/_form.html.erb` for `category_id` and populate it with your list of Categories. You can use this to select a "Parent" for your categories.

Then you can do stuff like:

```
# Get parent category's name
<%= somecategory.parent.name %>

# Iterate through subcategories
<% someothercategory.subcategories.each do |category| %>
  <%= category.name %>
<% end %>
```

Using a gem like Ancestry will give you a lot more flexibility when it comes to working with these categories and their associations though.

A bit about how Ancestry works:

> Ancestry stores a path from the root to the parent for every node.
>   This is a variation on the materialised path database pattern. It
>   allows Ancestry to fetch any relation (siblings, descendants, etc.) in
>   a single SQL query without the complicated algorithms and
>   incomprehensibility associated with left and right values.
>   Additionally, any inserts, deletes and updates only affect nodes
>   within the affected node’s own subtree.

Comment: I like the 1-level of nesting suggestion. The question is, how do I then reference the nested categories? Would I have to create a new table called `parent_category` & `subcategories` with for both? Would I have to add anything to my `routes.rb`?

Comment: @marcamillion No, you don't need extra tables or routes. They are still just "categories". See my edits.

Comment: That looks awesome. How do I create a subcategory? E.g. `cat = Category.first`. Assign a subcategory to `cat`. I would think that you would want to use the `id` of the subcategory, but not quite sure how that works here. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh...I see...interesting. Ok Thanks! `category_id` on a `category` table....kinda meta.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how Ancestry gem works, but in nested solutions the main concern is - speed.
If the model Category doesn't subject to a hi-freq creation, try [awesome_nested_set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set). It uses not only parent_id, but :lft and :rgt columns which are significantly speed up the searching of mutually nested objects, when children are very, very much... 30-50 categories and thousands of products - one of that case.

Comment: Know anything about Rails_admin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966643/routing-error-for-a-model-with-a-join-table-and-has-many-through-in-railsadmin ??