# Heroku - ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR: column category_products.desc does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

I am using RailsAdmin and this is the error I get when I click on my model `CategoryProduct` within RailsAdmin.

This is what the error looks like:

```
Started GET "/admin/category_product" for 67.230.41.62 at 2012-12-21 23:20:07 +0000
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  column category_products.desc does not exist
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...ry_products".* FROM "category_products"  ORDER BY category_p...
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "category_products".* FROM "category_products"  ORDER BY category_products. desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0):
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:     120:       %tbody
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:     121:         - @objects.each do |object|
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:     122:           %tr
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:     123:             %td
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:     124:               = check_box_tag "bulk_ids[]", object.id, false
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:     125:             - if @other_left_link ||= other_left && index_path(params.except('set').merge(params[:set].to_i != 1 ? {:set => (params[:set].to_i - 1)} : {}))
2012-12-21T23:20:07+00:00 app[web.1]:     126:               %td.other.left= link_to "...", @other_left_link, :class => 'pjax'^
```

These are my `category`, `product` & `category_product` models:

`Category.rb`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: categories
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
    has_many :category_products do
         def with_products
           includes(:product)
         end
       end

  has_many :products, :through => :category_products

  def top_products(number)
    category_products.with_products.order("purchases_count DESC").limit(number).map {|c| c.product} # product included
  end

end
```

`Product.rb`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: products
#
#  id          :integer          not null, primary key
#  name        :string(255)
#  description :string(255)
#  price       :float
#  vendor_id   :integer
#  created_at  :datetime         not null
#  updated_at  :datetime         not null
#  image       :string(255)
#

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :price, :vendor_id, :image, :category_ids
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    belongs_to :vendor
    has_many :category_products do
           def with_categories
             includes(:category)
           end
    end

    has_many :categories, :through => :category_products

  def top_categories(number)
    category_products.with_categories.order("purchases_count DESC").limit(number).map {|c| c.category} # category included
  end

end
```

`Category_Product`

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: category_products
#
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  product_id      :integer
#  category_id     :integer
#  purchases_count :integer          default(0)
#  created_at      :datetime         not null
#  updated_at      :datetime         not null
#

class CategoryProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :category_id, :purchases_count

    belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :category

  validates_uniqueness_of :product_id, :scope => :category_id
end
```

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: did you ensure that heroku db migrated with category_product primary key? RailsAdmin miss id again: "ORDER BY category_products. desc" must be "ORDER BY category_products.id desc"

Comment: Yep...I sure did. When I check the `CategoryProduct` model in the Heroku console, this is what I see:  `CategoryProduct
=> CategoryProduct(id: integer, product_id: integer, category_id: integer, purchases_count: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)`

Comment: Btw, how do I fix that query? Not quite sure how to change that query....or if I should.

Comment: Ok....this is very weird...I just did a push to fix something else, and it seems to have fixed this issue.

Comment: is that production/development env? and db too?

Comment: Heroku = production env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was on Heroku's side (I assume).

I did another push with a different update to the codebase and this problem seemed to go away.

Comment: i knew it i knew it i knew it )

Comment: well thats not the problem on heroku side ... what i have experience is that db get updates but the application remains unaware of db alterations so one should use heroku restart after running the migrations.

Comment: Running `heroku restart` fixed a similar issue for me. The codebase was working fine on local and staging build machine, but broken (`undefined method 'category_id' for #<Product`) on Heroku. This cleared it up without changing the codebase since there was *nothing to fix*. :)